# If a file hasn't been chosen then don't upload

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I'm having trouble with this form. I want the user to be able to edit an item in the datebase. They chose which item they want to edit on one page and get sent with a GET to the editing page. The GET has the id of the item they need to edit.

The editing page loads with the details of the item inserted into the user form (apart from the name of the file) this field is left blank. I am trying to do some logic that checks if the user has chosen a file.

If they haven't then this field should be ignored as I will presume the user is happy with the file that is already uploaded.

If they chose a file then this means they want this to be the new picture. Only then do I want to run the logic to upload the picture and insert its name into the database.

I'm getting my POST details by saying:

```
$clean_pic = $_POST['pic'];
```

I am then saying if it's blank do nothing otherwise run the upload:

```
if($clean_pic = ''){}
    else{
```

It's not working. Any ideas how I should find out if its blank? Cut down code:

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) 
{

    // validate 'pic': must consist of alphanumeric characters only.
    $_POST['pic'] = isset($_POST['pic']) ? $_POST['pic'] : '';
    //if(preg_match('/\.(jpg|gif|jpeg)$/i',$_POST['pic']))
        //{
        $clean_pic = $_POST['pic'];
        //}
    //else
        //{$error++; $errmsg .= 'Invalid pic. ';}

}


if (isset($_POST['add']) && ($error==0)) 
{                   


    if (!isset($_POST['pic'])) { echo"test1";}
else {echo"test222";}

    /*tied this too but it didnt work (it will always display result 1):
       if (!isset($_POST['pic'])) { echo"test1";}
   if (isset($_POST['pic']))  {echo"test222";}*/

}

else //output error messages 
{
/////////render form
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="save"><fieldset>
<table id="site-form">
    <tr>
    <td class="one_of_three"><label>Item Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td class="two_of_three"><input type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" value="<?php echo"$db_name";?>"/></td>
    <td><label class="errors" id="fileNameError">&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="one_of_three"><label>Picture:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td class="two_of_three"><input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="pic"/></td>
    <td><label class="errors" id="picError">&nbsp;</label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="one_of_three">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="two_of_three"><input name="add" id="save_button" type="submit" value="Update"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../">Cancel</a>.</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset></form>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `if (!isset($_POST['pic']))`?

Comment: im trying this now but it doesnt work:     'code' $_POST['pic'] = isset($_POST['pic']) ? $_POST['pic'] : '';
 if($_POST['pic']==''){do nothing} else {upload file} 'code'

Comment: i dont understand probably what you want to achieve. i thought that you want to do something only when user selected a file and it could be done in such way:`<?php
if (!isset($_POST['pic']))
{
 echo('Select a file');
}
else
{
 // do something
}
?>`

Comment: thanks for the hellp but this still not working. i tried the code you gave me. ive altered the post so you can see wht the new code is. the first isset test for pic seems to be influencing things. if i run the code as it is i will get echo test222 as the result if i choose or dont choose a file. if i take that line out then i get echo test1 as the result, again test1 is the result if i choose or dont choose a file. that just gave me an idea i think the else might be not working properly....

Answer (score 0):

You cant access the file using 'id' attribute ('pic'). You have to use the value of 'name' attribute ('userfile'). You can check whether the file is uploaded or not using $_FILES array in php.

if(isset($_FILES) && isset($_FILES['userfile']) && (trim($_FILES['userfile']['name']) != '') ) {

//Your upload code here

}

else

{

//No file uploaded

}

Comment: thanks, but you've totally misunderstood the question. the question ask if they have chosen a file in the form then run the upload logic. if they havent chosen a file then dont run the upload logic. checking to see if the file has been uploaded is therrefore not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to things :
 one is $_POST['pic'] is an array 
 second one is in the form you have to use enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute.

Comment: can you tell me what is the output of print_r($_POST['pic'])

Comment: print_r($_POST['pic'])  always returns nothing